# Formatting header and page numbering

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, koma-script

I'd like you to help me with something rather simple:

1. I want to remove the numbering on the first page of my document but not the header.
2. The header must be always the same, now in the second page it says "References."

```
\documentclass[twoside,parskip=half,numbers=noendperiod,abstract=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

%Bibliography
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{Bibliography-APA_w_header.bib}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}    
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,
bottom=25mm, headsep=10mm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.} 
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalfont\large}
\setkomafont{author}{\normalfont\large}

%Header
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\ihead{}\ohead{}\chead{\headmark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
\markboth{Title \textbullet{} Course \textbullet{} 2015}
{Title \textbullet{}
Course \textbullet{} 2015} 

\KOMAoptions{headsepline=true}

\title{Elbør, Jancka und dann Zickler}
\subtitle{Subtitle of the paper}

\author{\textsc{Name Surname}\\[2ex]
\normalsize Unversity Name\\ 
\normalsize \href{mailto:name@domain.com}{name@domain.com}}
\date{}

\setlength{\skip\footins}{11mm}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
\unskip\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}

\begin{abstract}
\KOMAoptions{parskip=half}
\noindent Er hörte leise Schritte hinter sich. Gerade jetzt, wo er das Ding \parencite{book} seines Lebens gedreht hatte und mit der Beute verschwinden wollte! Hatte einer seiner zahllosen Kollegen dieselbe Idee gehabt, ihn beobachtet und abgewartet, um ihn nun um die Früchte seiner Arbeit zu erleichtern? Weil wir haben gesehen viele Male solche Spiel! Oder gehörten die Schritte \parencite{web-noauthor-nodate} hinter ihm zu einem der unzähligen Gesetzeshüter dieser Stadt. Die Schritte wurden lauter und lauter, er sah eine dunkle Gestalt \parencite{web-noauthor-date} um die Ecke biegen. Fieberhaft irrten seine \parencite{web-author-nodate} Augen durch die nächtliche Dunkelheit und suchten einen Ausweg. War jetzt wirklich alles'' Danke. Offensiv, offensiv ist wie machen wir in Platz \parencite{web-author-date}. Wir haben gesehen viele Male solche Spiel! \parencite{blog-date}.
\end{abstract}
\vspace{7mm}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Keywords}: assignment \textperiodcentered{} project \textperiodcentered{} keyword
\end{center}

\medskip
\setlength\columnsep{24pt}
\begin{multicols}{2} % Two-column layout throughout the main article text

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par

\printbibliography

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you boil down your document till everything is obvious? -1, no research effort. :-(

Comment: @Johannes_B This is the reduced version of my paper. I tried erasing the page number using "\thispagestyle{empty}" but it also erased the header. In regard to the header, I have no clue how to avoid it from changing and I found no information about that. It seems that for some people it's not a big deal to have a different header on the last page of their documents. However, I'd like to have all the header with the same information.

Comment: Rather than `set`ting the komafont, you should `add` to it. `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\itshape}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main problem with the header changing is that you set it to be `\headermark`. Therefore, an update to `\headermark` will update the header accordingly. Instead, set to to some fixed value that doesn't depend on anything else.

You can place a condition in your header/footer for printing content depending on the page number:

```
\chead{Title \textbullet{} Course \textbullet{} 2015}
\ofoot{%
  \ifnum\value{page}>1 \thepage\fi}
```

The above prints the same header everywhere, and the footer text only *after* page 1. You can decide which header/footer content to be conditional, of course.

---

It may be more advisable to use a different page style for the first page. Then, set the entire document page style to `scrheadings` and `\thispagestyle{firstpage}` for the first page:

```
\newpagestyle{firstpage}
  {{}{\makebox[\linewidth]{Title \textbullet{} Course \textbullet{} 2015}}{}}% header content
  {{}{}{}}% (Remove) footer content
\chead{Title \textbullet{} Course \textbullet{} 2015}
\ofoot{\thepage}

%...

\pagestyle{scrheadings}% Entire document page style
\thispagestyle{firstpage}% First page page style
```

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yup, I misread. Updated; thanks.

Comment: Neat solution! Tried it and worked fine!

Answer (score 4):

You could set the `scrlayer-scrpage` option `manualmark` to get the same header on every page even if `\headmark` is used. But it is easier to set `\chead*` directly.

The package `scrlayer-scrpage` sets the pagestyle to `scrheadings` automatically.

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead*{Title \textbullet{} Course \textbullet{} 2015}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
```

You can simple define a new pagestyle `firstpage` by cloning `scrheadings`:

```
\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{firstpage}{\cfoot*{}}
```

Then use `\thispagestyle{firstpage}` on the first page.

Note that `\chead*{<text>}` and `\cfoot*{\pagemark}` need KOMA-Script version 3.14 or later. With version 3.12 or 3.13 use `\chead[<text>]{<text>}` and `\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}` to get the same header and footer for pagestyle `plain` and `scrheadings`.

Comment: There's something wrong when I try to compile my file using this solution:

LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.32 \chead*{T
              itle \textbullet{} Course \textbullet{} 2015}

Comment: You need at least KOMA-Script version 3.14 to use `\chead*` and `\cfoot*`. Up to date is version 3.15. With version 3.12 or 3.13 you have to use `\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}` and `\chead[...]{...}` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\chead*{Whatever you want to have as your header}` with an up to date KOMA bundle.

```
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot[]{\pagemark}
\chead*{Whatever you want to have as your header}
```

Well actually, the first command resets all fields and clears them. The second  sets the central foot field with the page number, except for plain pages, which aren't really used in an article document anyways. You have to use @Werners solution there. 
The third command sets a static header, also for plain pages. As Werner already explained, `\headmark` is dynamically updated.